# Insertar texto letra a letra en widget Text

Tags: python, tkinter, formato, ventana

Quiero hacer aparecer un texto dentro de una caja de texto, pero letra a letra, no de golpe, insertando una breve pausa tras cada carácter. Esto lo puedo hacer perfectamente en la consola mediante print, pero en ventana no funciona, se espera todo el tiempo de todas las letras y luego las hace aparecer de golpe, todas juntas. ¿Sería posible controlar la aparición de un texto letra a letra? Gracias

```
conversa=Text(ventana)
texto="un texto cualquiera"
retardo=0.25
for i in range(0,(len(texto))):
    sleep(retardo)
    conversa.insert(END, texto[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

Puede usar el método `update` para forzar que los cambios aparezcan en widget Text o en cualquier otro widget.

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

ventana = Tk()

conversa=Text(ventana)
conversa.pack()

texto="un texto cualquiera"
retardo=0.25
for i in range(0,(len(texto))):
    sleep(retardo)
    conversa.insert(END, texto[i])
    conversa.update()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Otra solución es programar la acción usando el método `after` en lugar de usar un bucle:

```
from tkinter import *

ventana = Tk()

conversa=Text(ventana)
conversa.pack()

texto="un texto cualquiera"
retardo=250  # retardo de milisegundos


def insertar_la_siguiente_letra(i=0):
    if(i >= len(texto)):
        return

    conversa.insert(END, texto[i])

    # Programa para ejecutar la función después de un retraso
    ventana.after(retardo, insertar_la_siguiente_letra, i+1)


insertar_la_siguiente_letra()

ventana.mainloop()
```

Una solución usando `after` es más preferible porque la función `sleep` en un bucle ralentiza las actualizaciones de la ventana. Puede notar una diferencia si intenta resaltar el texto que se muestra al insertarlo.

[image: El animación]